# How to make a simple score by clicking the enemy or object?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

My game is whac a mole. I'm using this code in frame 
`score=0;`

and this is for the button to click to gain score

```
on (release) {
    score++;
}
```

The score doesn't appear. Why is that and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess you are only updating the variable and not the display of it. If you have a texfield showing the score somewhere, you could set `myTextfield.text = score;`.
Anyhow, you are using very, very old code (AS2). I would advise against learning AS that way and going with AS3.